# fetch data from 2 tables where data exist in other table or not

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables user and attendance while login I want to check if today's attendance is present or not.

**tbl_user**

```
user_id
name
username
password
```

**tbl_attendance**

```
att_id
user_id FK from user
create_date timestamp
```

If user login first time then show attendance=0 else 1.
I have tried this:

```
select u.*,ifnull(a.attendance_id,0) as attandance 
from users u, attendance a 
where u.username = "emp1" and u.password = "password@123" 
and role <> 'customer';
```

Comment: Can you show us what your have tried?

Comment: select u.*,ifnull(a.attendance_id,0) as attandance from users u,attendance a  where u.username = "emp1" and u.password = "password@123" and role <> 'customer

I don't know how to set time

Comment: Are you really storing plain text passwords in your database?  _Don't do that!_.  Instead, hash the password first, then store it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery instead .

```
SELECT A.*, IFNULL(SELECT 1 
                   FROM tbl_attendance B 
                   WHERE B.user_id=A.user_id 
                    AND DATE(B.create_date)=CURRENT_DATE LIMIT 1, 0) attendance
FROM tbl_user A 
WHERE A.username="emp1" AND A.password="password@123";
```

I see no role column in any of the two tables, so it shouldn't appear in your query, else you can use it as you did.